# Socket.io, saved image on server isn't opened

Tags: image, server, socket.io

I'm trying to save image from canvas on server, but image isn't opened (isn't supported format).

Client:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var sendData = () => {
  const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

  socket.emit('sendImage', dataURL.toString('base64'));
};
```

Server:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('sendImage', (imageData) => {
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/image.png', imageData, function (err) 
  {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('It\'s saved!');
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

Client:

dataURL.toString('base64') has base64 encoded data in the format of

data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA…
So we need to get rid of the mime type and encoding information at the front.

```
var sendData = () => {
  const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL().toString('base64');
  const toSend = dataURL.split(',')[1];

  socket.emit('sendImage', toSend);
};
```

Server:

Now we need to convert its buffer.

```
fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/image.png', Buffer.from(imageData, 'base64'), function 
  (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('It\'s saved!');
  });
```